# How to make a <button> in a VS form not post back to server

Tags: visual-studio, bootstrap-4

I am creating a page in VS 2017 that uses bootstrap modal for a popup. When I place the  for the modal inside the asp.net form the modal opens and then closes right away.  When I place the button outside the form the modal works fine. I have tried using an asp.net button and OnclientClick but that doesn't work. I have tried onClick in the button, didn't work.  I tried type="button", didn't work. Is there anyway for a to stop the button from causing a submit. Here is the code.

```
 <form runat="server">
----some code



    <div runat="server" id="btnContinue" class="row justify-content-center">
        <asp:Button ID="continue" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" text="Continue Login"/>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary ml-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Request Account</button>
    </div>

</form>
        <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h5>
                   <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>Effective 22 May 08, access to the F-15 TADS site will require an approved DD Form 2875.</p>
                 </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised that you can still build web forms in VS2017!

Anyway, if you don't specify `type` attribute on a `<button>`, it will default to `type=submit`. That might be the reason why you saw the modal opened and closed right away.

To trigger the modal, a simple `<button>` with `type=button` should work. It doesn't need to be within the `<form runat="server"></form>`:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal"
    data-target="#myModal">
    Request Account
</button>
```

It should still work even the button is inside `<form>`, as long as it specifies `type="button"`.

[image]

Comment: I tried the type=button it didn't work in the form.  By doing that nothing happened. I move the code out side the form and it worked fine. I would like to keep it in form for looks.  What do you mean your surprised I can still build web forms in vs2017.  They have not gotten rid of them.

Comment: @TomMauldin: I just created the default web form project in VS2017. The gif showed the button still works inside the form.